# How can I draw a rubber band line while picking the second point after first point picked?

Tags: c#, revit-api

In Revit API, I want to draw a ModelLine which can preview before second point picked.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

I resolved.
Try this below code:

```
public class Command : IExternalCommand
    {
        public Result Execute(
          ExternalCommandData commandData,
          ref string message,
          ElementSet elements)
        {
            UIApplication uiapp = commandData.Application;
            UIDocument uidoc = uiapp.ActiveUIDocument;
            Application app = uiapp.Application;
            Document doc = uidoc.Document;

            Selection sel1 = uidoc.Selection;
            List<XYZ> tempXYZ = new List<XYZ>(1);
            XYZ p1 = sel1.PickPoint();
            XYZ p2 = null;


            //tempXYZ.Add(p3);

            ModelCurve visualLine = null;
            using (TransactionGroup tGroup = new TransactionGroup(doc))
            {
                tGroup.Start();

                Redraw:
                using (Transaction t = new Transaction(doc))
                {                   
                    t.Start("Step 1");

                    Line line = Line.CreateBound(p1, getP3(uidoc));

                    Plane geomPlane = Plane.CreateByNormalAndOrigin(doc.ActiveView.ViewDirection, doc.ActiveView.Origin);
                    SketchPlane sketch = SketchPlane.Create(doc, geomPlane);
                    visualLine = doc.Create.NewModelCurve(line, sketch) as ModelCurve;
                    doc.Regenerate();
                    uidoc.RefreshActiveView();                  
                    goto Redraw;

                    t.Commit();     
                }
                tGroup.Commit();
            }
        return Result.Succeeded;
        }

        private XYZ getP3(UIDocument uidoc)
        {
            UIView uiview = GetActiveUiView(uidoc);
            Rectangle rect = uiview.GetWindowRectangle();
            System.Drawing.Point p = System.Windows.Forms.Cursor.Position;
            System.Windows.Forms.Cursor.Position = new System.Drawing.Point(p.X, p.Y);
            double dx = (double)(p.X - rect.Left) / (rect.Right - rect.Left);
            double dy = (double)(p.Y - rect.Bottom) / (rect.Top - rect.Bottom);
            IList<XYZ> corners = uiview.GetZoomCorners();
            XYZ a = corners[0];
            XYZ b = corners[1];
            XYZ v = b - a;
            XYZ p3 = a + dx * v.X * XYZ.BasisX + dy * v.Y * XYZ.BasisY;
            return p3;
        }
        //Convert Document hiện hành thành UIView
        private UIView GetActiveUiView(UIDocument uidoc)
        {
            Document doc = uidoc.Document;
            View view = doc.ActiveView;
            IList<UIView> uiviews = uidoc.GetOpenUIViews();
            UIView uiview = null;

            foreach (UIView uv in uiviews)
            {
                if (uv.ViewId.Equals(view.Id))
                {
                    uiview = uv;
                    break;
                }
            }
            return uiview;
        }
    }
```

Comment: This code don't work on ViewSection